# How to validate the absence of shared commits prior to rebasing them?

Tags: git, rebase

We work with git around a reference repository, whose history must never be rewritten.

Contributors are free to rewrite their local history as long as it hasn't been shared; but while the reference repository will reject any attempt to push such rewritten history (at least in cases where this results in a branching rewound), we would like to catch this before they attempt to push and find themselves needing to undo the rebase, and so provide a script (to be run manually if need be) to detect such a forbidden rebase, i.e. one that involves shared commits, before it happens.

Since we go to the trouble of providing a script for that, we want to use this to catch additional scenarios. For instance, if local branch `feature` was based off shared branch `refactor` which was itself based off shared branch `main`, then it turns out we want to ship `feature` before `refactor`, we want the script to catch the naive `git rebase main feature` which would rebase all the commits in `feature` but not in `main`… including the commits from `refactor` that branch `feature` has in its ancestry (the correct command in that case being, of course, `git rebase refactor feature --onto main`). So detecting the presence of `refs/remotes/*/feature` is not enough, since that won't be a factor in this scenario.

Comment: Remember that it's phenomenally easy to forget you pushed the first few commits of a branch before leaving for holidays "just in case", once you have completed your work after these holidays.

Answer (score 0):

The best I could figure is:

```
git for-each-ref 'refs/remotes' --format='%(refname)' | xargs git merge-base -a HEAD | xargs git log --no-decorate ^$1
```

From a commit ancestry set algebra perspective, this selects the commits which satisfy `'refs/remotes/**'.reduce((x, accum) => accum or (isAncestorOf(HEAD) and isAncestorOf(x)), false) and not(isAncestorOf($1))`, of which there must be none for the check to clear (and otherwise, list them to show why the rebase is forbidden).